# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un calendario en c#

Tags: c#, calendar

soy nuevo en c# y estoy intentando hacer un programa de calendario. Para ello he creado un form con varios usercontrol que hacen de ventanas. En un usercontrol he intentado haacer el calendario, primero he colocado un FlowLayoutPanel (llamado: "day_container"), en el he se mostrarán los dias del calendario, he escogido la medida de 120; 90 px para cada panel (que harán de casillas de cada dia) y he creado un usercontrol (llamado: "UserControl2"). He probado ha mostrar los dias antes del día uno del mes:

```
private void DisplayDays()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        DateTime startofthemonth = new DateTime(now.Year,now.Month,1);

        int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(now.Year, now.Month);

        int dayoftheweek = Convert.ToInt32(startofthemonth.DayOfWeek.ToString("d")) + 1;

     for (int i = 1; i < dayoftheweek ; i++) //aqui surge el problema
     {
            UserControl2 usC2 = new UserControl2();
            day_container.Controls.Add(usC2);
     }
    }
```

Y no funciona, como tal no obtengo ningún error al compilar, pero el Usercontrol2 no se muestra, he estado investigando y creo que puede ser por el bucle "for" porque al retirarlo, se muestra solo 1 Usercontrol2 en el day_container y tengo por supuesto que se debería mostrar todos los dias hasta el 1 de este mes. Desgraciadamente no es así. Abajo les muestro
los elementos:

-Primero el day_container:
[image: Imagen del day_container]

-Luego el UserControl2:
[image: Imagen del UserControl2]

Espero que me puedan ayudar. Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! si agregas dos en lugar de uno, a mano, se ven los dos?

Comment: Hola! gracias por ayudarme, he usado tu consejo y he creado otro usercontrol (lo he llamdo usercontrol3) y lo he agregado como el anterior. Y si, se muestra correctamente en la posición de martes. Pero no entiendo a donde quieres llegar, debería crear más usercontrol?

Comment: a que depures tu app... tu for, esta iterando mas de una vez? no deberias crear mas controles.. que pasa si agregas dos veces el UserControl2? no estara poniendo uno arriba del otro, no haciendole caso al flow panel? verificaste en el arbol de controles que esten los dos? verificaste que las posiciones de los dos no esten superpuestas?

Comment: Después de muchas pruebas y depuraciones he comprobado que no, el for, al no responder true no se ejecuta por lo tanto no se muestra el user control. Mi pregunta ahora es, se supone que el for funciona correctamente, por que no responde true?

Comment: no entiendo esto ultimo.. como que el for no responde true? el for itera la cantidad de veces que le digas que itere.... querras decir que no esta iterando nada? porque transformas un int en string para luego transformarlo en int?

Comment: A eso me refiero, lo siento por no usar un lenguaje adecuado, como dije soy inexperto y novato en el tema, la verdad es que no lo hice a aposta, use un tutorial para una de las partes y debi a ver hecho eso por error. Crees que el problema puede venir directamente por la transformación? Un error puede surgir por seguir malas practicas de código?

Comment: es que no tenes un error.. tenes un problema de logica en tu codigo... si el for no itera, es porque la condicion se cumple antes de entrar... por ejemplo, un domingo o lunes no va a entrar nunca, porque domingo es 0 y lunes es 1... sera por eso? si haces debug, que valor tiene dayoftheweek . Y confundir un iterador (for) con un condicional (if) es algo mas basico, por mas que seas novato...

Comment: Bueno, creo que el código que he escrito no solo no cumple con las reglas básicas, si no que no tiene una gran lógica. Por lo tanto creo que lo mejor para mi salud mental va a ser probar con otro metodo mejor, creo que existirán mejores maneras de hacerlo. De todos modos, te agradezco que me hayas ayudado y disculpas por el tiempo perdido. No sé como agradecertelo más, he visto que te puedo comprar un cafe en linea, pero los pagos son solo para argentina.

Comment: A veces, empezar de vuelta sirve.. lo de los controles de usuario esta perfecto... ahora, que queres que itere? sobre que cosas?? fijate como estan armados los calendarios... siempre estan todas las semanas, y el primer dia se ubica en el cuadro que corresponde... para calendarios, una grilla (por poner un ejemplo burdo) es mas comodo que un flow panel.. al fin y al cabo, siempre a la izquierda vas a tener o un lunes o un domingo...